# ORA-00904: invalid identifier issue with alias in SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle 11g is giving me an invalid identifier error with the following code:

```
SELECT idproduct, SUM(quantity) AS amnt_sold
FROM [table]
GROUP BY idproduct
HAVING amnt_sold >= 3
```

By deduction, the error is with the HAVING statement and the alias I've used, but I can't figure out for the life of me what the issue is, even after some researching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The column alias isn't available in the `HAVING` clause. (Just as specified by ANSI/ISO SQL.)

Either put the `SUM()` in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT idproduct, SUM(quantity) AS amnt_sold
FROM [table]
GROUP BY idproduct
HAVING SUM(quantity) >= 3
```

Or, wrap the query up in a *derived table*, and then use the amnt_sold column name.

```
SELECT idproduct, amnt_sold
FROM
(
  SELECT idproduct, SUM(quantity) AS amnt_sold
  FROM [table]
  GROUP BY idproduct
) dt
WHERE amnt_sold >= 3
```

Comment: Just for completeness, `HAVING` cannot use named expressions in Oracle. As far as I know this is valid in MySQL, MariaDB, and H2 only.